# Set user agent with WebView with react-native

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I want to modify the user agent string in a WebView so that on the server side I can detect that the request has come from my react-native app. I want to do this using the source prop in the WebView.

How do I do this for IOS and Android?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You just can set it as a prop in your WebView.

I'm doing the following:

on iOS (I set the userAgent in AppDelegate.m)

```
NSString *deviceType = [UIDevice currentDevice].model;
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
NSString *oldAgent = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"navigator.userAgent"];
NSString *newAgent = [oldAgent stringByAppendingString:@" MYAPPNAME - iOS - "];
newAgent = [newAgent stringByAppendingString:deviceType];
NSDictionary *dictionnary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:newAgent, @"UserAgent", nil];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:dictionnary];
```

on Android (I set the userAgent in JS in my WebView):

```
<WebView
    userAgent={DeviceInfo.getUserAgent() + " - MYAPPNAME - android "}   
    ref={"WEBVIEW"}
    automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
    source={{uri: this.state.url}} />
```

now I'm always having a userAgent like "DeviceInfo - MYAPPNAME - Platform". We're doing the same like you and it works how it's supposed to do.

Comment: You can use the [rn-ios-user-agent](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rn-ios-user-agent) package to do the iOS side in javascript.

Comment: `userAgent` prop is not working for Android. I am using `^7.5.2` version for rn-webview and `0.61.5` for RN. Maybe is there any other solution for it?

Comment: Note that this notation is not following the user agent specs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent MYAPPNAME/version (Android) does follow this spec

Answer (score 5):

For Android, you only need to set `userAgent` attribute, for example:

```
<WebView
source={{ uri: "https://stackoverflow.com" }}
userAgent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36"
 />
```

For iOS, you need to add the code below inside the method `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` (before the line `return YES;`) in `AppDelegate.m` implementation:

```
NSString *userAgent = @"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36";
NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:userAgent, @"UserAgent", nil];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:dictionary];
```

Answer (score 2):

This library now provides a method to get the userAgent for both ios and android:

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-device-info#getuseragent

```
this.state = { 
   userAgent: "",
}

componentDidMount = async () => {
   this.setState({ userAgent: await DeviceInfo.getUserAgent() })
}

<WebView
source={{ uri: "https://stackoverflow.com" }}
userAgent={this.state.userAgent}
>
```

Answer (score 1):

windows phone user-agent for android and ios

Android:

```
mWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows Phone 8.0; Trident/6.0; IEMobile/10.0; ARM; Touch; NOKIA; Lumia 920)");
```

IOS:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows Phone 8.0; Trident/6.0; IEMobile/10.0; ARM; Touch; NOKIA; Lumia 920)" forkey:@"UserAgent"]];
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested for IOS, placing it in the ```AppDelegate.m``` file and I receive the error ```No known class method for selector 'dictionaryWithObject:forkey;'```

Comment: use in the same class that you use uiwebview

Answer (score 1):

just add this to user agent you can update the versions in future, I used is as google login was giving me issue

userAgent="Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; Android SDK built for x86 Build/LMY48X) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/81.0.4044.117 Mobile Safari/608.2.11"

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but a workaround.

I realised that what I wanted to do was determine if a request to my ruby on rails server was from mobile safari or from the webView of my react-native app. To solve this, I just installed the `browser` gem, and then did

```
browser = Browser.new(request.user_agent)
from_app = browser.platform.ios_webview?
```

If someone can give a clear answer to my original question, I will select that answer rather than mine.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS, you can use WKWebView instead of WebView which support userAgent setting.
https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Reference.md#useragent

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36", @"UserAgent", nil];
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:dictionary];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

in AppDelegate.m
import WKWebView

```
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>
```

inside the method `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` the code below will append customString to current device userAgent

```
  WKWebView *webView = [WKWebView new];  
  NSString *userAgentP1 = [webView valueForKey:@"userAgent"];
  NSString *userAgentP2 = @" customString";
  NSString *userAgent = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", userAgentP1, userAgentP2];
  NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:userAgent, @"UserAgent", nil];
  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:dictionary];
```

UIWebView is deprecated and some other solutions propose hardcoding the same userAgent for all devices

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -4):

This is a terrible idea. Just use a custom header:

```
X-MY-CUSTOM-HEADER = MyAppName.
```

Comment: This is what I want to do, but how do I actually set it in the react-native WebView source prop?

Comment: Ah, sorry. I misread the question and missed the WebView part. Not sure if there is a way to inject custom headers into requests coming from the webview.

Comment: It makes sense that you should not set this parameter on a page by page basis, but set it as part of the configuration parameters of the app.  If I accept your answer rather than Beto Caldas's answer,   can you please explain where and how in the Xcode project do I set X-MY-CUSTOM-HEADER and does this leave all the other header information the same e.g. IOS version etc?