# React Native WebView missing session cookies on iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, cookies, uiwebview

My WebView should display a web page that has a cookie authentication.
The page expects a session-id cookie acquired on login.
To authenticate I send the login request to the website using fetch().

When the login is successful I can see that proper cookies are received.
On success, I'm starting the WebView.

**It works perfectly on Android but not on iOS.**

Yesterday I tried a lot of different approaches suggested on SO, like getting cookies manually with react-native-cookies, but nothing helps.

Below is a sample component that does the same thing as my app does. I thought that the problem may be in the configuration of my app, so I created this extremely simple example and it has the same problem.

```
export default class App extends Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    response: null,
  }
}

async componentDidMount() {
  const response = await this.logIn()
  console.log('LogIn completed', response)
  this.setState({
      response: response
    })
}

async logIn() {
  const url = 'myurl/login?email=email&password=password'
  const headers = {'MyHeader': 'Header text'}
  try {
    let response = await fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: headers,
      // credentials: 'same-origin',
      credentials: 'include',
    })
    return Promise.resolve(response)
  } catch (error) {
    return Promise.reject(error)
  }
}

render() {
  const url = 'myurl/dashboard'
  const headers = {'MyHeader': 'Header text'}
  return (
    <WebView source = {{
      uri: url,
      headers: headers
    }}
    />
  )
}
}
```

I tested it on iOS 9 and iOS 11 simulators, and on an iOS 11 device.

To sum up the question: **Why cookies I've got with fetch aren't passed to WebView on iOS only.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the problem. The lack of cookies was only the consequence of the wrong authorisation caused by wrong 'User-Agent' header. 
I was trying to pass User-Agent in the WebView headers. It works fine on android but requires a workaround for iOS.
To set the User-Agent header on iOS you need to change UserDefaults from the AppDelegate.

```
NSString *userAgent = @"YourUserAgentString";
NSDictionary *dictionnary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:userAgent, @"UserAgent", nil];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:dictionnary];
```

Thanks to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37917932/3055378

Comment: Cool that you found out! Thanks for posting about this on StackOverflow. This way others will be able to find your answer via Google. This was hard to do with the React Native Community group on Facebook.

Comment: Hey I have been struggling with this for days now, could you please elaborate on the solution you provided? What should "YourUserAgentString" correspond to. What was the user agent you specified?

Comment: Hi @JohnDoe. I don't remember exactly but the user agent string was an app specific string specified by our backend devs.

Answer (score 2):

Use property `sharedCookiesEnabled={true}` in webView. It's working in my case.